# Three responsive boxes next to each other where a button needs to be aligned at the bottom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have three boxes next to one another that contain a heading, an image and a button on the bottom. The last box has text below the image and the image is shorter in height than the first two. I made a code pen for reference:
https://codepen.io/jessiemele/pen/aLmoYz. You can see when you scale the screen down, as the image gets smaller the button on the third box moves with it but the other two stay in line with one another. How can I get that button on the third box to stay inline with the other two?
my html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="trio">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<h3>The Enrollment Process</h3>
<img class="homeImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/340x280" /><a 
class="homeCTA" href="/timeline-pricing">View Enrollment Timeline &amp; 
Pricing</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<h3>The Curriculum</h3>
<img class="homeImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/340x280" /><a 
class="homeCTA" href="/curriculum">View the Curriculum</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<h3>Happenings</h3>
<img class="homeImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/340x149" />
<div class="box">
<p class="calenderDays">May 20th – Spring Cleaning Day<br/>May 29th – Closed 
for Memorial Day</p>
</div>
<a class="homeCTA" href="#">View the Full Calendar</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
a.homeCTA {
color: #ed3e27;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 48px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid #ed3e27;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 10px;
}
img.homeImg {
width: 100%;
}
.col-sm-4 {
width: 30%;
float: left;
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
h3 {
text-align: center;
}
p.calenderDays {
padding: 20px 0 30px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1280px) {
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 50px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS to use flex on these elements:

```
.trio {
  display: flex;  
}
.trio > * {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.trio > * .homeCTA {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XejEYN

(The last rule aligns the `.homeCTA` at the bottom of the equally high flex containers)

If you only need this above a certain width, put it into a media query, like

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1280px) { ... }
```

Comment: thank you and that would work, but I can't use flex because it's not compatible with IE :( I have to have browser support back to IE 9

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion in this problem, but I'm not sure if it is ok for you.
I change a structure of an html. So I extract buttons from one container in your code where in this contaiener were located images, texts, and buttons and put buttons in other ways.
Here is example 
Your html should be something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>

    <a class="link" href="#">Link1</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link1</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Link1</a>
</div>
```

and css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
} 

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box:first-child {
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.box { 
    margin: 1% 1%;
    width: 30.6666666667%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    height: 350px;
}

.box:last-child {
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.link:first-child {
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.link {
    margin: 1% 1%;
    width: 30.6666666667%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.link:last-child {
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```